# custom data in drupal

Tags: drupal-7

very new to drupal. I need to create section of my website that contains a directory of 300 companies. I think it be best to create separate databasetables and not included this data in drupal's nodal architecture. Is there a typical/best practise way to manage custom data in drupal

Comment: This would be better at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/ but the short answer to your question is: No you should probably use drupal core features, content types, taxonomies, fields and display the directory with views module.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to take a look at the Drupal 7 [Entity API](http://www.istos.it/blog/drupal/drupal-entities-part-1-moving-beyond-nodes). If you want to use your own database scheme within Drupal that would be the way to do it. I have been using it for a while and it sounds exactly like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The way I did it was to get the module that allows you to use php in pages (PHP filter) and then write a simple database wrapper. Drupal provides a good theme framework that makes it pretty easy to make themed tables with support for sorting etc.